# What does =+ mean in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been studying operator overloading and i cant understand this, whenever i use `s1=+s2`
answer is `s1=1 s2=1` and when i use `s2=+s1` i get `s1=2 s2=2`
please explain

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class score
{   private:
    int val;
    public:
    score()
    {   val=0;  }
    score operator+()
    {   score temp;
        val=val+1;
        temp.val=val;
        return temp;    }
    void show()
    {   cout<<val<<endl;    }
};
main()
{
    score s1,s2;
    s1.show();
    s2.show();
    +s1;
    s1=+s2;
    s1.show();
    s2.show();
}
```

Comment: the same thing as `s1 = +s2;`

Comment: oh, i see it now...thanks

Comment: @sameeralakshitha That is incorrect, you are thinking of `s1 += s2;` This is not the same thing. It's equivalent to `s1 = (+s2);`, which is `s1 = s2;` in most cases.

Comment: @sameeralakshitha `s1=+s2;` is not the same as `s1 = s1 + s2;`.  `s1=+s2; => s1 = +s2;` and `s1+=s2 => s1 = s1 + s2;`

Comment: Off topic: That + operator is violates convention. + should not modify the objects it's invoked on just like  3 = 2+1 doesn't modify the value of 2 or 1. More here: [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  s2=+s1
> ```

Means merely nothing more than applying the unary [`operator+()`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to the `rvalue` provided with the [`operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)'s parameter.

That boils down to the same statement as

```
s2 = (+s1);
```

There's no combined operator like `operator+=()` for that.

That would have no effect at all, unless these operator functions are overloaded for specific (*non primitive*) types.

Comment: I believe `operator+` is called first. From my understanding of your answer, it seems to imply the opposite.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The opposite of what?

Comment: Your answer says that `operator+` is called on the result of `operator=`, but it's the `operator=` that should be acting with the result of `operator+`. `s2.operator=(`s1.operator+()`);`

Comment: The opposite of the truth; Francois is right, but I think it's just a language barrier with the way you phrased "provided with the operator="

Comment: @Boundary I tried to clarify that now.

Comment: It's a bit better. Prob good enough now (particularly since this is a dupe anyway)